# How to read Safari Cookies using Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cookies, safari

As far as I know Safari cookies are in binary format.

Is there a way to read them in a Cocoa Application?

Any pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a parser for Swift that can do this for you. I needed this because `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()` doesn't give you access to the global cookies when sandboxed.

https://github.com/icodeforlove/BinaryCookies.swift